# How can make emacs immediately compile a file I load?

Tags: start-up, compilation

Usually when I load a project, I want to compile it once right away, be it to again see the compilation error I was working on or just to build the dependencies of the checkout, so I don't have to wait for the entire build when I've actually done some changes.

Of course I can simply press `C-c m` (which I've mapped to `recompile`), but is there a way to achieve the build without any extra cue?

Comment: You project have specified language or it's a common question?

Comment: I just want to execute the standard `compile` command right after loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add hook into `init.el`

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (string= major-mode "c-mode")
              (recompile))))
```

for `c-mode` to recompile it automatically when you'll `find-file`.